# C# Using byte[] directly in CreateRemoteThread and LoadLibrary injection

Tags: c#

I am using CreateRemoteThread to inject a dll into a target process and it works perfectly, currently it takes the parameters:

```
inject(string procName, string dllPath);
```

and reads dllPath to byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllPath);
```

I want to skip this process and give it the byte array to work with directly since I download encrypted bytes off my server. Note, my target platform is x64 which is why I'm not using jLibrary.

If I go: byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(someFile) to test it out, the injection fails so I tried to convert the byte[] from my existing file to char[] then encode it to ascii but it also fails. How should I go about doing this?

The class is:

> bool injectDLL(uint processToInject, string dllPath)
>           {

```
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(desiredAccess, 1, processToInject);

        if (processHandle == INTPTR_ZERO) return false;

        IntPtr loadLibraryAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (loadLibraryAddress == INTPTR_ZERO) return false;

        IntPtr argAddress = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)dllPath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0X40);

        if (argAddress == INTPTR_ZERO) return false;

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllPath);

        if (WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, argAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
            return false;

        if (CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, (IntPtr)null, INTPTR_ZERO, loadLibraryAddress, argAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null) == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            return false;
        }

        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Where does it go wrong? Are you getting an error in either process? Are you returning false in any of these if-branches?

Comment: @Glubus I get no errors, the injection "succeeds" however the dll does not get properly mapped onto the process. The DLL is meant to display text in the target process but it fails to do so

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but paths in the Windows API are Unicode. The real Windows API are the functions ending in W; The A ones are crutches for Windows 95. So, I suggest you switch to the W functions and use Encoding.Unicode (UTF-16) if you need text in bytes rather than string.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to convert your string to an array of bytes.

Just use string::ToCharArray()

```
IntPtr bytesRead = IntPtr.Zero;
WriteProcessMemory(proc.Handle, loc, dllpath.ToCharArray(), dllpath.Length, out bytesRead);
```